# ng-show display the contents before the page finished loading?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this very simple approach to toggle between hiding and showing some contents:

```
<a ng-click="cred=!cred" href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;"><strong>Admin Credentials</strong></a><br />
<p class="lead check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="cred">User Name: <strong>Mohamed</strong><br /> Password: <strong>password</strong></p>
```

The controller has no code yet. but I noticed that when the page is loading, the contents of the class `lead` are showing for milliseconds and then it disappear?
but that is not what I need, either anyone- I think. I want it to be initially hidden, but it seems that angular is waiting for the page to finish loading and then it applies the `ng-show` expression!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-show items flash before loading if they aren't required.

ng-cloak along with the necessary CSS should be used to hide them until it is known whether or not the element is needed.

```
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` to avoid css-animations in this case. `ng-show` and `ng-hide` are triggering class manipulations to interact with your css-animations. If you still want css animations after the page has been loaded, you need to bind a second `$scope` for "show/hide" for "after page load handling".

```
<p class="lead check-element animate-show-hide" ng-if="cred" ng-show="toggle">
     User Name: <strong>Mohamed</strong><br /> 
     Password: <strong>password</strong>
</p>
```

The second approach is to not bind your css animation into your element while its not needed. This will avoid the animation. In this case you don't need to use `ng-if` (but it may breaks your "hide" animation").

```
<p class="lead check-element" ng-class="{'animate-show-hide': cred }" ng-show="cred">
     User Name: <strong>Mohamed</strong><br /> 
     Password: <strong>password</strong>
</p>
```