# Disable the two way binding in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mddialog

I'm using the Angular material `md-dialog`, when the user click the button (edit button) to show the dialog, it takes the current object (a row in a table) and pass it to the `showDialog` function, fill the dialog fields with its values:

```
<button ng-class="showDialog(task)">Open dialog</button>
```

showDialog function:

```
$scope.showDialog = function (task) {
    $scope.taskToEdit = task;
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        contentElement: '#taskEdit',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        clickOutsideToClose: true
    });
};
```

But whenever I edit the values in the dialog there is a live binding in the back in the table, where the table is getting the same keystrokes values as the the dialog, and if I clicked outside (cancel the edits) these values stay persist.
So is there a way to disable this two way binding and just pass a copy of the object to the `showDialog` function not a reference?

Comment: Is there a way to pass a copy of the object? Yes, there is. Create a copy, and pass it to the showDialog function. Are you asking how to create a copy of an object? What does the object look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Hey Mohamed, I still waiting for response of you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717303/ng-show-display-the-contents-before-the-page-finished-loading/42717354#42717354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `angular.copy()` should do it. There are a lot of approaches to this but you should use a simple solution - thats why `angular.copy()` should do it this time - try:

```
$scope.taskToEdit = angular.copy(task);
```

This does not disable the E2E binding in AngularJS but it will prevent updating the `$scope` in your main view.